# Removing Entries Created SPModification for Non-Default Zone

Tags: sharepoint

It is a well known issues that SPModification only removes entries from the default zone. What are people using as a work around. I'm implementing something and I'd like to know how others are working around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never had to use it (knew the issue tho) and in my book it is a combination of 2 techniques:

1- Opening the web.config based on the SPWebApplication (see AlternateUrls property for additional zones)

```
SPWebApplication webApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Parent;
Configuration webconfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/", webApp.Name);
```

2- Using good ol' [XmlDocument manipulation](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030907.asp) with XPath and friends